# Using array value as object field name

Tags: javascript

If I have an array and an object is it possible to use the array values as field name to get the object field value?

Like this:

```
var x = ['foo', 'bar'],
    y = {
        foo: 'foo,foo',
        bar: 'bar,bar'
    }

for (var i = 0, l = x.length; i < l; i++) {
    console.log(y.x[i]);
    // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined 
}
```

Except, this doesn't work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/VDCDZ/)

**Update**

what if one of the object fields is a method like :

```
y = {
    foo: 'foo,foo',
    bar: function () {
        alert('');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as you are dealing with a variable key

```
console.log(y[x[i]]);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VLn69/)

`y.x[i]` tries to read a property `x` of `y` which does not exits so the `[0]` throws an error.

Comment: what would you do with  functions

Comment: yes if one of them is a function i notice it will yield the function as string

Comment: @MinaGabriel do you want to invoke the function

Comment: just add `()` to the function reference like `y[x[i]]()`

Comment: @MinaGabriel see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VLn69/3/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VLn69/4/

Comment: @MinaGabriel sorry I used jQuery in the fiddle will fix now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41746/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-mina-gabriel)